# Implementing the Metropolis Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, mcmc

I am trying to write a MCMC program based on the Metropolis Algorithm in Haskell and I am having issues with sampling from probability distributions (generating pseudo-random numbers) and structuring the program. For now I am happy with using a generator with a hardcoded seed than deal with complexity of dealing with IO.

It seems that I should use the state monad to keep track of the random generator state, the previous markov chain state, chi squared value and the acceptance count between each step of the algorithm and then finally collect all the markov chain states and the last acceptance count. Is this the best/idiomatic way to do this? and if so what should the layout of the program should be (i.e. type signatures of the proposal function and the metropolis step function etc.).

I have seen some sample programs that deal with random numbers where a list of random numbers of a particular length is generated from some kind of a probability monad and then threaded through some simple functions to perform the computation.  I really would like to avoid this inside out form of the program if it possible.

Edit: Temporarily removed WIP code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some feedback on writing idiomatic Haskell.

- Unless you are writing monadic code, using `do` in pure functions
  (ie. `constructMuTable`, `metropolis`) is very un-idiomatic Haskell.

  Instead of

  ```
  foo = do
      let x = ...
          y = ...
          z = ...
      bar x y z
  ```

  just write

  ```
  foo =
      let x = ...
          y = ...
          z = ...
      in bar x y z
  ```

  or use `where` instead of `let ... in ...`.
- eta-reduce. In some places (`zVec`, `muVec`, `sigmaVec` in `main`) you have written `(\x -> f x)`. This is equivalent to just `f`, modulo `_|_`, `seq` etc.
- use `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. You have lots of `V.Vector Double`, which stores boxed `Doubles` and can be inefficient. For primitive types like `Double`, use unboxed vectors for (potentially) much faster code using less memory.
- avoid indexing lists with `(!!)` if possible. Use `Data.Vector` instead as `V.!` is `O(1)` while `(!!)` is `O(n)`.
- It seems like you might be able to use the `State` monad here to clean up your code. However, in its current imperative form it's difficult for me to see the transformation.

Perhaps you can try to apply some of the recommendations I've given and simplify some of the large, dense functions and then higher level feedback on your algorithm will become more apparent.